# Can max86150 use in wrist?

Tags: sensor, wearable, ecg

I am looking for an SPO2 sensor where I can mount on the wrist.

but most data sheets do not specify whether sensors can be used in wrist-mounted devices.

they mention fitness or just wearables, I tested max30102 and max30100, work only for finger no other skins,

[max86150](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX86150.pdf) also mentions ECG and spo2 ppg workable, but not mention whether spo2 can be measured from the wrist.

found that green led for wrist due to low blood flow compared to fingers

also for spo2 red led or IR is must

how to find out before purchasing whether the sensor works for the wrist?

Comment: Have you tried speaking with Maxim?

Comment: Diagram on 1st page contains text "left hand ... right hand  (for ecg) ... Human Finger ..." . A funger is mentioned on page 17. If they were targeting wrists as well you'd expect at least one mention in a 49 page data sheet.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=wrist+pulse+sensor+schematic&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj06rzuifLpAhU7D7cAHZGOACwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=wrist+pulse+sensor+schematic&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQDFAAWABg_z5oAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=8BveXvSyEbue3LUPkZ2C4AI&bih=1025&biw=2048&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839) image search may be useful. Note that pages relate to wrist and / or finger sensors .

Comment: Green LED is intended for wrist HR measurement; SPo2 requires at least two wavelenghts (Red/IR) and cannot be measured on just any part of the skin. (Earlobe perhaps?) Fitness instead of medical diagnostic because Red/IR alone can be fooled by CO or CH4 poisoning.